# Advanced parametrization in JDBC PreparedStatements

Tags: java, jdbc

Are there anyway to parametrize the table in a PreparedStatement?

```
select * from ? where id=?
```

If not, what is the best approach to do that or, are there any other way to do it without loosing the advantages of a PreparedStatement?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is that you **cannot** parameterize a tablename in a prepared statement. You have to contruct the sql with string concatenation. Basically prepared statements are used for column values and not for the table names.

The best I can think of is to use `string.format` like this:

```
String sql = String.format("select * from $1%s",  yourtable);
```

Answer (score 0):

We could do in the following way

```
 "select * from "+table_name+" where id=?";
```

PreparedStatement allow you to provide dynamic query parameters in where clause only

Comment: @CPUTerminator , lets read OP's post again 
*what is the best approach to do that or, are there any other way to do it without loosing the advantages of a PreparedStatement?*
In the above approach, no one is losing advantages of **Prepared Statement**

Answer (score 0):

Use placeholder in place of table name and then replacing that with your tablename.

```
String strQuery = "INSERT INTO $tableName (col1, col2)
                   VALUES (?,?);";
```

and replace when you come to know the tablename as below:

```
String query =strQuery.replace("$tableName",tableName);
stmt =connection.prepareStatement(query);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String table_name= // get tablename 
String sql= "select * from" +table_name+" where id=?";
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have your PreparedStatement with an SQL query as you stated you can do:

```
int yourID = 1;
String tablename = "table";
String query = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " where id = ?";´
PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(query);
statement.setInt(1, yourID);
```

It will replace the `?` with `1`. If you have multiple `?` you can set those like

```
statement.setString(2, "YourString");
```

Check 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html for more Information.